# C language Altera Monitor compliation error :(

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

So im trying to compile a c language code sample on altera monitor program, and I kept getting this error:

> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

im unsure what is going on, I read around for error reports by other users which mentioned that there might be a typo or syntax error in my coding, but I cant seem to find any. Can someone offer some insight into my errors :(

```
#include "nios2_ctrl_reg_macros.h"

/* function prototypes */
void interrupt_handler(void);
void the_exception (void);

/* global variables */

int LED_counter;

// extern indicates to the linker that the variable has been declared
// elsewhere. This declaration does not allocate any memory.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

volatile int * InPort_KEY1 = (int *) 0x3040;
volatile int * InPort_Counter = (int *) 0x3030;
volatile int * OutPort_GREENLED = (int *) 0x3020;
volatile int * Out_Flag = (int *) 0x3010;
volatile int * Out_LEDR = (int *) 0x3000;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



/* The assembly language code below handles CPU reset processing */
void the_reset (void) __attribute__ ((section (".reset")));
void the_reset (void)
/***************************************************************************
* Reset code. By giving the code a section attribute with the name ".reset"*
* we allow the linker program to locate this code at the proper reset *
* vector address. This code just calls the main program. *
***************************************************************************/
{
asm (".set noat"); // Magic, for the C compiler
asm (".set nobreak"); // Magic, for the C compiler
asm ("movia r2, main"); // Call the C language main program
asm ("jmp r2");
}

/* The assembly language code below handles CPU exception processing. This
* code should not be modified; instead, the C language code in the function
* interrupt_handler() can be modified as needed for a given application.
*/
void the_exception (void) __attribute__ ((section (".exceptions")));
void the_exception (void)
/**************************************************************************
* Exceptions code. By giving the code a section attribute with the name *
* ".exceptions" we allow the linker program to locate this code at the *
* proper exceptions vector address. *
* This code calls the interrupt handler and later returns from the *
* exception. *
***************************************************************************/
{
asm ( ".set noat" );                    // Magic, for the C compiler
asm ( ".set nobreak" );                 // Magic, for the C compiler
asm ( "subi sp, sp, 128" );             // make space on the stack
asm ( "stw et, 96(sp)" );               // save exception temporary
asm ( "rdctl et, ctl4" );               // read control register ctl4 ipending
asm ( "beq et, r0, SKIP_EA_DEC" );      // Interrupt is not external
asm ( "subi ea, ea, 4" );               // if external must decrement
                                        // ea by one instruction for
                                        // external interrupts, so that
                                        // the interrupted instruction
                                        // will be run
asm ( "SKIP_EA_DEC:" );
asm ( "stw r1, 4(sp)" );                // Save all registers
asm ( "stw r2, 8(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r3, 12(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r4, 16(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r5, 20(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r6, 24(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r7, 28(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r8, 32(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r9, 36(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r10, 40(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r11, 44(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r12, 48(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r13, 52(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r14, 56(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r15, 60(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r16, 64(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r17, 68(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r18, 72(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r19, 76(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r20, 80(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r21, 84(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r22, 88(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r23, 92(sp)" );
asm ( "stw r25, 100(sp)" );             // r25 = bt (skip r24 = et, because
                                        // it is saved above)
asm ( "stw r26, 104(sp)" );             // r26 = gp
                                        // skip r27 because it is sp, and 
                                        // there is no point in saving this
asm ( "stw r28, 112(sp)" );             // r28 = fp
asm ( "stw r29, 116(sp)" );             // r29 = ea
asm ( "stw r30, 120(sp)" );             // r30 = ba
asm ( "stw r31, 124(sp)" );             // r31 = ra
asm ( "addi fp, sp, 128" );
asm ( "call interrupt_handler" );       // Call the C language interrupt
                                        // handler
asm ( "ldw r1, 4(sp)" );                // Restore all registers
asm ( "ldw r2, 8(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r3, 12(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r4, 16(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r5, 20(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r6, 24(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r7, 28(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r8, 32(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r9, 36(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r10, 40(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r11, 44(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r12, 48(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r13, 52(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r14, 56(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r15, 60(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r16, 64(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r17, 68(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r18, 72(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r19, 76(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r20, 80(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r21, 84(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r22, 88(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r23, 92(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r24, 96(sp)" );
asm ( "ldw r25, 100(sp)" );             // r25 = bt
asm ( "ldw r26, 104(sp)" );             // r26 = gp
                                        // skip r27 because it is sp, and 
                                        // we did not save this on the stack
asm ( "ldw r28, 112(sp)" );             // r28 = fp
asm ( "ldw r29, 116(sp)" );             // r29 = ea
asm ( "ldw r30, 120(sp)" );             // r30 = ba
asm ( "ldw r31, 124(sp)" );             // r31 = ra
asm ( "addi sp, sp, 128" );
asm ( "eret" );
}

/***************************************************************************
* Interrupt Service Routine
* Services the counter interrupt.
*
* ipending - Control register 4 which has the pending external interrupts
***************************************************************************/

void interrupt_handler(void)
{
int ipending;
NIOS2_READ_IPENDING(ipending);
if (ipending & 0x1) // PIO interrupt level 0
{
*(InPort_Counter + 0x3)=0x1; // clear PIO edgecapture interrupt
*(Out_Flag)=1;
*(Out_LEDR)=LED_counter++;
*(Out_Flag)=0;
}
// else, return
return;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/**************************************************************************
* This program demonstrates use of interrupts in the DE2 Basic Computer.
**************************************************************************/
int main(void)
{int old_KEY1=0;
int LEDG_state=0;
int atm=0;
int temp;
/* set up rising edge triggered interrupts for the counter PIO input */
*(InPort_Counter + 0x2) = 0x1; // enable counter MSB interrupt
// set interrupt mask bit for counter IRQ level 0
NIOS2_WRITE_IENABLE(0x1);
// enable Nios II interrupts (presumably PIE bit in status set to 1)
NIOS2_WRITE_STATUS(0x1);
while(1){ // normal code infinite loop
temp=*(InPort_KEY1);
// check for a rising edge on the KEY1 output
if(old_KEY1 & ~(temp) & 0x1){
// service KEY[1] pressed
*(OutPort_GREENLED)=LEDG_state;
LEDG_state=~LEDG_state;
}
old_KEY1=temp; // update old_KEY1
for(atm=0;atm<10000;atm++);
}
}
```

Comment: There's usually more to that error message: specifically what function the linker was not able to find.  The error means that your code called some function that doesn't exist, either because of a typo in the function name, or because you didn't link with the correct libraries.

Comment: Please [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) your code.